# Why is it convention to let vectors equal each other

Tags: conventions, mathematics

[image]

I understand that the magnitudes of the two velocities equal each other. But I don't understand why it is more correct to use the convention. As $\vec v_1- \vec v_2$ should not equal $0$ it should $2 \vec v_1$ given they are equal magnitudes.

I was under the impression that two vectors are equal if and only if they have the same magnitudes and directions.

Comment: Your impression is correct. That's why you should make sure you denote vectors by $\vec{v}$ or $\boldsymbol{v}$, so you don't confuse with numbers.

Comment: What did you read that made you think there is a convention to say that the two vectors you drew are equal rather than negatives of each other?

Comment: If you add those two vectors together you clearly get $0$ (head to tail method). So $\vec v_1+\vec v_2=0$. In your drawing this is the case. $\vec v_1=-\vec v_2$ What's the issue here? Who told you this other incorrect convention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a feeling you are seeing something like this :

$$\vec{v}\text{ = a vector called }v$$

$$v := |\vec{v}|\text{ = the magnitude of a vector called }v$$

I've seen this sort of thing fairly often, and in that case if you have two vectors $\vec{u}=-\vec{v}$ then it correct to say $u=|\vec{u}|=v=|\vec{v}|$.  Saying that two vectors have the same magnitude is not the same as saying they are equal.